# Adding objects to an array in a hashtable

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, hashtable

I want to create a Hashtable which groups files with the same name in arrays so I can later on work with those to list some properties of those files, like the folders where they're stored.

```
$ht = @{}
gci -recurse -file | % {
    try{
        $ht.Add($_.Name,@())
        $ht[$_.Name] += $_
    }
    catch{
        $ht[$_.Name] += $_
    }
}
```

All I'm getting is:

```
Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At line:8 char:13
+             $ht[$_.Name] += $_
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: `if ($ht[$_.name]) { $ht[$_.name] += $_ } else { $ht[$_.name] = ,$_ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't *reinvent* the wheel. You want to *group* files with the same name, use the  `Group-Object` cmdlet:

```
$groupedFiles = Get-ChildItem -recurse -file | Group-Object Name
```

Now you can easy retrieve all file names that are present at least twice using the `Where-Object` cmdlet:

```
$groupedFiles | Where-Object Count -gt 1
```

---

You are getting this error because if your code hits the `catch` block, the current pipeline variable (`$_`) represents the *last error* and *not* the current item. You can fix that by either storing the current item an a variable, or you use the `-PipelineVariable` advanced cmdlet parameter:

```
$ht = @{}
gci -recurse -file -PipelineVariable item | %  {
    try{
        $ht.Add($item.Name,@())
        $ht[$item.Name] += $item
    }
    catch{
        $ht[$item.Name] += $item
    }
}
```